# Connecting to mongodb in docker

Tags: c#, mongodb, docker

I'm trying to connect to my mongodb that is running in a docker container from a console application (Visual Studio C#) but can't get it done.
I don't get any errors when running my application but when I check the mongodb inside the docker container it doesn't show any inserted documents of my application.

This is the code snippet how I was trying to connect to my mongodb:

```
var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017");
var db = client.GetDatabase("test");
var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("testColl");

var document = new BsonDocument {
    {"Name", "h" },
    {"Dep", "ADI" }
};
```

I think I'm doing something wrong when creating the mongodb in my docker Container.. I simply pulled the latest image of mongo and then did following:
`docker run --name myMongoTestDb -d mongo`

Comment: Provide C# code which you tried to connect to mongodb, Dockerfile and docker is in which env..?

Comment: Are you sure your code is set to create the mongo database and not just edit it? could be you're trying to add records to something that doesn't exist

Comment: Your docker mongo is it accessible externally ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things could possibly be an issue here:

1) Make sure you're calling Insert on the collection after you've created the document

```
collection.Insert(document)
```

2) Make sure you're exposing the 27017 port to your localhost from the container with the `-p` argument

```
docker run --name myMongoTestDb -p 27017:27017 -d mongo
```

**More Reading:**

Exposing Ports - https://github.com/wsargent/docker-cheat-sheet#exposing-ports
Inserting documents with C# - https://mongodb-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-csharp-driver.html#insert-a-document

Comment: Thanks a lot. I haven't exposed the Port. Now everything works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should expose 27017 port as well. Try

> docker run --name myMongoTestDb -p 27017:27017 -d mongo